# Creating n children each with their own pipe

Tags: c, pipe, fork, pipeline, interprocess

I'm having trouble understanding `pipe` and `fork`, at least implementing it in practice. I would like to create `n` children each with their own pipe.

I thought of doing something like:

```
int main(void) {
    int fd[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        pipe(fd);
        r = fork();

        if (r == 0) {
            // do child stuff
        } else if (r > 0) {
            // do parent stuff
        }
    }
}
```

But doing this would result in the children making processes of their own which isn't what I want.

Moreover, how would you make it so that the parent and child run concurrently, where the child is constantly writing to the pipe and the parent, with access to the pipe to each child, reads from it, does something with it, then discards it so that the child can write something new to the pipe?

Comment: Put a `break;` in the block after `if (r == 0)`, or more likely an `exit()`.

Comment: I would also like for the parent to work with the children together. For example, the child processes will constantly write random integers to their respective pipe and have the parent pick which random number is the smallest among the pipes that have something written to them. I've searched online and people have mentioned threading but is this possible with pipe?

Comment: "n children, each with their own pipe".  Does the parent keep the other end of each pipe open, or is child M connected to child M+1, or ...?  Who has the other end of the pipe?  That will greatly determine the structure of the loop.

Comment: The parent will only be reading from the n pipes where each child will have a pipe that it only writes to. Sorry if I wasn't clear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need an array of file descriptors big enough for one pair of file descriptors for each child.

The parent code will create the pipes.  Each child processes should close the pipes of any sibling processes.  The exact mechanics of that depend on how you create the pipes; there are multiple workable options.

The `if (r == 0)` code will execute the child process and should ensure it exits rather than continuing the loop.

The parent process will simply continue creating the other child processes before going into its own processing loop.

You're going to need to decide how to determine which children have written data so that the parent can read it without blocking.  You might use `select()` or `poll()` or a variant on those, or the parent might make the read ends of the pipe non-blocking, or …

In a comment you ask "…people have mentioned threading but is this possible with pipe?", to which the answer is "yes, it's possible — though it isn't clear that it is necessary or desirable".

> Would you happen to have sample code doing what you've described?

It's probably simpler to write than to find.  The `be_childish()` function is responsible for doing whatever a child should do.  It should not return.  If it does, that will be reported as a failure.
You've not said much about what the child processes do, so it's hard to fill in the gaps there.

```c
int main(void)
{
    enum { NUM_CHILDREN = 5 };
    int fd[NUM_CHILDREN][2];

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CHILDREN; i++)
    {
        pipe(fd[i]);
        int pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0)
           …error exit…
        if (pid == 0)
        {
            // Child
            // Close sibling pipes
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                close(fd[j][0]);
                close(fd[j][1]);
            }
            close(fd[i][0]);   // Close read end of pipe
            be_childish(fd[i][1]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CHILDREN; i++)
        close(fd[i][1]);       // Close write end of every child's pipe

    // setup complete, unless you need to make the read end of the pipes non-blocking
    // do parental stuff, reading from the various child pipes

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CHILDREN; i++)
        close(fd[i][0]);       // Close read end of every child's pipe
    int corpse;
    int status;
    while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
        printf("Child %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);

    return 0;
}
```

<sup>*Beware: this code has not been near a compiler, much less run.  There are probably bugs in it.*</sup>

Comment: Would you happen to have sample code doing what you've described? I'm not exactly sure what you mean in the last paragraph, what sort of written data are you referring to? If the children were standalone, random number generators for example and I want the parent to go through each pipe to see each child's randomly generated number and output the smallest, how would the implementation look?

Comment: And I saw the remainder of your comment after I'd typed code and submitted my comment.  How many random numbers would each child generate?  How do you plan to send them over the pipe (binary data or printable data)?  Is the number of random numbers itself random?  In what range?  Which PRNG (pseudo-random number generator) would you use?  Is repeatability an issue?  What do you use as the seed?  Etc.